# Use angularjs directive templates from $templateCache in karma tests

Tags: angularjs, templates, karma-runner

I know how to [load templates in my karma tests using the ng-html2js preprocessor](https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing). However, in our project we have a *templates.js* file already that looks like so:

```
angular.module("myApp").run(
    ["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put(
            "app/directive-template.html",
            "<span>Some fancy template.</span>");
    ...
});
```

It is generated with the [gulp-angular-templatecache](https://github.com/miickel/gulp-angular-templatecache) plugin. This works great for production but fails for tests. The file is included in the *karma.conf.js* and loads correctly, but the run-function is only executed **after** the tests have executed.

How can I make karma wait for the run phase so the templates are loaded before the tests are executed?

Answer (score 1):

if you beforeEach your myApp module, then your template will be loaded

I use gulp ng-hmtl2js to create my template.js file
and the entry looks like this:

```
    //app template
gulp.task('template_app', function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/**/*.tpl.html')
        .pipe(ngHtml2Js({
            moduleName: "template.app"
        }))
        .pipe(concat('app.template.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});
```

then in my test I do:

`beforeEach(module('template.app'));`

See the answer that helped me @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/28832167/1843436