# Gulp angular unit testing directive templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, gulp, browserify

I read many post on internet and SO but couldn't find any solution that works
I am trying to write unit test for a directive and want the html files to be served from template cache

I am using Gulp as a build tool

The gulp task for test looks like this

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    karma.start({
        configFile:__dirname + '/' + config.test.karmaconf,
        singleRun: false
    }, done);
});
```

and in `karma.conf` , I have defined

```
    browserify: {
        debug: true,
        transform: [['browserify-ng-html2js', {
            module: 'templates',
            extension: 'html'
        }]]
    }
```

In unit test , I declared

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('templates'));
```

but receiving

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET path/to/some.html
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend
```

I also tried to use `preprocessors` and `ngHtml2JsPreprocessor` in karma.conf but no success. Could anyone provide solution or point me how can I go about  debugging why the templates are not served?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

There are multiple ways you could go about doing that. Here's how I do it:

1. Use [gulp-angular-templatecache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache):

```js
gulp.task('bundle-common', function() {
  return merge(
    // Store all html files in $templateCache
    gulp.src([
      appDir + '/common/**/*.html'
    ])
    .pipe($$.angularTemplatecache({
      root: 'common'
    }))

    // Append everything else: directives, tests, etc.
    gulp.src([
      appDir + '/common/**/*.js'
    ])
  )
  .pipe($$.concat('common.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'));
});
```

This will output a file named `common.js` with all your html templates and directives in it.

It will look somewhat like this:

```js
angular.module("templates").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
$templateCache.put("common/a-great-eye.html","<div>lidless, wreathed in flame, 2 times</div>");}]);

angular.module("common")

.directive('aGreatEye', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'common/a-great-eye.html'
    };
});

...
```

2. In `karma.conf.js` load `common.js`:

```js
     files: [
      '../vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      '../vendor/angular/angular.js',
      '../vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      '../public/js/common.js'
    ]
```

3. In your test file reference the `templates` module:

```js
describe('Unit testing great quotes', function() {
  var $compile,
      $rootScope;

  // Load the common module, which contains the directive
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('templates');
    module('common');
  });

  // Store references to $rootScope and $compile
  // so they are available to all tests in this describe block
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  it('Replaces the element with the appropriate content', function() {
    // Compile a piece of HTML containing the directive
    var element = $compile("<a-great-eye></a-great-eye>")($rootScope);
    // fire all the watches, so the scope expression {{1 + 1}} will be evaluated
    $rootScope.$digest();
    // Check that the compiled element contains the templated content
    expect(element.html()).toContain("lidless, wreathed in flame, 2 times");
  });
});
```

### Debugging

Start your test in Chrome browser and hit Debug button. Then open Developer Console.

Few tips:

- You can add breakpoints in your tests.
- Make sure that there are no errors in console window, especially injection errors. If you do, verify that all the js files you requested in `karma.config.js` (they will be listed in Developer Console) are loaded correctly and contain the code you need (angular, templates, directives, etc.).